# Logging in to Magento's admin backoffice is slow

Tags: magento

It takes about 20 seconds to login to the admin backoffice. During this time load would spike (from 0.02 to 0.20)

Yet I see no "slow queries" in the mysql log. I've optimized all the tables.

Is there some way to hunt down the source of this slow down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which browser are you using? The Magento admin can be very slow in some browsers i.e. Internet explorer. I recommend using Chrome or Firefox for admin work, especially adding/editing products. If you are generally looking at ways to speed up Magento then here is a good place to start:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140327173649/http://www.gxjansen.com/101-ways-to-speed-up-your-magento-e-commerce-website/

Comment: I've started using Chrome for the backend specifically because of the total rework of their Javascript interpreter for speed and flexibility. The category and manufacturer attribute options list are limited by the browser's JavaScript execution capabilities. In our categories section, the difference between running Category Maintenance on an XP Single processor system and a 64 bit Windows 7 system on a quad core processor under IE7 has the speed difference of at least an order of magnitude (10 times faster). Chrome shows yet better response.

Answer (score 1):

The admin panel pulls in a lot of files and is heavily javascripted. Turning on things like mod_deflate and mod_expires can help tell your browser to not download these files as often.

Answer (score 1):

Magento is extremely resource intensive and the admin interface does not use any caching. A lot of it depends on the hardware your site is on. For any site is decent traffic and heavy admin use, the base line should be a dedicated dual quad core server with 24-32mb of ram, especially if you have the db and web on the same server. Any shared server will just not cut it. Cloud based solutions vary, we have had some good results with splitting db and load balanced web in a cloud environment. Make sure you have apache and mysql properly tuned based on the memory of the server and use a php accelerator like apc.